# Directly give a new Control an EventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looping a collection of strings, coming from a database; for each entry, I create a new Button which is then added to a FlowLayoutPanel.
The Text of each Button is set to the current item in the string collection.

I'd like to assign an EventHandler to the Click event of each Button, however I am only able to access the Properties of a Button.
I have to cast the last entry of the FlowLayoutPanel's Controls collection to Button and add the Event Handler to this instance.

Does anyone know the reason why I can't access anything else then Properties? Is there a cleaner way of coding that?

```
List<string> temp = Database.GetNames();

foreach(string s in temp)
{
    flp_main.Controls.Add(new Button()
    {
        Text = s.name
    });

    Button b = (Button)flp_main.Controls[flp_main.Controls.Count - 1];
    b.Click += B_Click;
}
```

Asking for Improvements on Code Quality

Comment: "*Does anyone know the reason behind why I cant access anything else then Properties*" -- nothing works until someone makes it work. [See this proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5176)

Comment: I'd write that `Button b = .... b.Click += ... flp_main.Controls.Add(b);`

Comment: `var btn = new Button() { Text = s.name }; btn.Click += B_Click; // Add the Control` -- Do you know how to determine which Button was clicked when the event is raised?

Comment: For asking code review, you should use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions.
I know, that I could turn the order around, to first create a Button, which I initialize how I please and add it afterwards, however there seems no logic reason to me, as to why I shouldnt be able to do in one step as suggested. canton7's Link however did clear up, that MS just didn't include it as of yet.
Thanks everyone!